# Knockout JS binnding the ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout JS, I am trying to bind the ajax result data to Knockout JS viewmodel, but I am facing the problem while binding the data to view, I have create model and viewmodel and I am getting the result from ajax. Need help.

Below is my code:

```
// ajax on page load///
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: baseUrl + 'api/xxx/xxx',
    data: UserProfileModel,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
        ////view model////
        userDetailsViewModel(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
        //jError('An error has occurred while saving the new part source: ' + jsonValue, { TimeShown: 3000 });
    }
});

//// view model///
var userDetailsViewModel = function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    self = this;
    self.user = ko.observable(new userModel(result));
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(userDetailsViewModel());
});

/// Model////
function userModel(result) {
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.userName = ko.observable();
}
```

Comment: userDetailsViewModel should be returning self. Currently its not returning anything. Hence View has no properties exposed by the ViewModel. Hence your code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `userDetailsViewModel` is a function that returns `undefined`. You'll either have to use `new` or create a `return` statement if you want it to create an actual viewmodel. E.g.:

   ```
   var UserDetailsViewModel = function(result) { 
     var self = this;
     self.user = ko.observable(new UserModel(result));
   };

   var mainUserDetailsViewModel = new UserDetailsViewModel(data);
   ```
2. You'll have to store a reference if you want to update your viewmodel from the scope of the ajax callback. Alternatively, you could make the ajax functionality *part of* the viewmodel. The easiest example:

   ```
   var mainUserDetailsViewModel = new UserDetailsViewModel(data);

   $.ajax({ 
     success: function(data) {
       mainUserDetailsViewModel.user(new UserModel(data));
     }
   });
   ```

   Make sure you use this model in your `applyBindings` call:

   ```
   ko.applyBindings(mainUserDetailsViewModel);
   ```

Note that I've used `CapitalizedNames` for functions that need to be instantiated, and `uncapitalizedNames` for instances of those functions. Following default naming conventions might help keeping track of what's what.

Comment: thanks,but binding to UI i am unable lik inside span tag <span data-bind="text:user().name"></span>

Comment: With the current `userModel`'s code, the actual data isn't processed at all. So `name` will always be `undefined`, resulting in an empty string. You'd have to set it by doing something like `this.name = ko.observable(result.Name)` in the constructor.

Comment: thanks,but i passed the value in constructor lik userModel(result) and i wont get any error ,but i assign this.name= ko.observable(result[0].name) or this.name= ko.observalbe(result.name) its shows error lik Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in userModel

Comment: If `result` can be undefined, you should check its value before trying to initialize a new person model. What does the `data` that gets passed to your `success` method look like?

Comment: thanks for u replay,but i am getting the data in the  result in usermodel when i passed the like userModel(result);but when i assign the lik this.name=ko.observable(result[0].name)or this.name=ko.observable(result.name) its gives me error "Cannot read property 'userProfile' of undefined"  on page load, am i making it myself complicated need help

Comment: I think you should use the debugger to step through your code and see what's wrong. If you can't get it to work, create a new question in which you clearly show the data that comes from the server, your viewmodel, _and_ your HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746416/ajax-data-binding-using-knockout-js  i have posted new question