# Handle ajax calls with knockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

So I've got an application that's using the Zomato API. Works great, but I keep getting an error that a knockoutJS binding (in this specific instance, `toClicked().zomatoInfo`) is undefined. Appears to work fine once the ajax call returns and the data populates appropriately. Is there some way to have knockoutJS handle this appropriately so we don't get any errors?

Here's my ajax request:

```
var zomatoGetData = function(input){
  var zomID = input.zomatoID;
  var result = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant?res_id=' + zomID,
    headers: { 'user-key' : 'myPersonalKey' },
    success: function(result) {
      return result;
    },
    error: function (thrownError){
      alert("Error! Here's what we pulled up: " + thrownError);
    }
  });
```

As a simplified example of one of the bindings:

```
<p id="location_description">
        The food and atmosphere is...
        <span data-bind="text: toClicked().zomatoInfo.responseJSON.user_rating.rating_text"></span>.
        (<span data-bind="text:toClicked().zomatoInfo.responseJSON.user_rating.aggregate_rating">X</span> 
        out of 5, rated by <span data-bind="text: toClicked().zomatoInfo.responseJSON.user_rating.votes">X</span> people.)<br>
</p>
```

Is there some way I can handle the ajax request so that knockoutJS handles it appropriately, or am I approaching how I'm binding these the wrong way? Appreciate any thoughts or ideas. Cheers!

Comment: It seems that is the answer to your problem: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Asynchronous-Dependent-Observables

Comment: I don't see `toClicked()` in your view model. But, if `toClicked()` is the async function, then that's not going to work. It seems like a bad way of designing your KO view models.

Comment: @serhiyb ah sweet, will take a peek at that and update here if I can figure out how it works. Cheers!

Comment: this question seems to be asking the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746416/ajax-data-binding-using-knockout-js